# Can I Extract, Translate, and Compare using Talend?

Tags: talend

I am evaluating Talend and I have little experience using the tool.  My question is  regarding audit.  Does Talend offer a way to run with an audit option that extracts the source data, transforms it and then compares the transformed data to the existing target data?  I would like a report that tells me which records would have triggered an update if the audit option had not prevented it.

I know that ETL's are triggered on change but I would want to run this audit without regard to changed timestamps.  That is, a query would specify what source records to audit.

I have done a search of the talend documentation but nothing jumped out at me.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Looking outside of Talend, I [found](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/03/22/etl-auditing/) where Tim Mitchell wrote:

> While I have not yet found an auditing framework with enough
>   customization to suit me, I have learned that it is possible to audit
>   ETL processes in a customized way without reinventing the wheel every
>   time. I keep on hand a common (but never set in stone) set of table
>   definitions and supporting logic to shorten the path to the following
>   auditing objectives:
>
> - Simple aggregate auditing of row counts, financial data, and other key metrics
> - Documentation templates for source-to-target mappings and transformation logic
> - Lightweight auditing of batch-level changes
> - Full auditing of every change made in the transformation process

So I guess that auditing is on me.

Comment: Like in any other ETL tool, this is something you need to build along with your ETL pipelines.  Also, why this question has `Oracle` and `Redshift` tags, the question has nothing to do with any database

Comment: Because I am ETL'ing from Oracle to Redshift but OK, I will remove the tags. Build along with the ETL pipeline; OK, I will look in that direction.

Comment: You are right saying "it's on me". Because every ETL process/DW implementation has it's own set of use cases. I have implemented 3-4 different variations of these in the past varying from just having audit tables and audit columns in fact/dim tables to running user customizable queries on the data daily and sending out reports/alerts when anomalies detected. So in short based on your use cases and your needs you need to build it.